# The proof of that a → b is equivalent to ¬b → ¬a using algebraic identities by ArsDigita

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

I'm noob practicing with discrete math problems, and not sure if the solution ArsDigita provided for this one is correct or not:

Prove that a → b is equivalent to ¬b → ¬a using algebraic identities.

Since the materials were provided 10 years ago, I'm not sure if there could be any correction and I haven't found any equivalent discussion. Therefore I'm here to seek for help.

The answer offered is like below:

a → b ⇔ ¬a ∧ b

⇔ b ∧ ¬a

⇔ (¬¬b) ∧ ¬a

⇔ ¬b → ¬a

I think it should be a → b ⇔ ¬a v b? Could you help to confirm this?

I'm really confused and would also have your advises to see if I should keep following ArsDigita's materials. I enjoy the professor's video lectures very much, but if there's error it would be very inefficient to keep on.

Please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, all of the $\land$s must be $\lor$ for the offered proof to make sense.

Comment: Thanks @HenningMakholm. Have you checked ArsDigita before? Or do you have any suggestion for the discrete math courses or materials?

Comment: x @Joseph: No I haven't, and I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A\to B\Longleftrightarrow\neg A\lor B\Longleftrightarrow \neg A\lor\neg\neg B\Longleftrightarrow \neg(\neg B)\lor(\neg A)\Longleftrightarrow \neg B\to\neg A$$

Comment: I see it now. The last step wasn't clear to me originally due to the ∨ and ∧ problem. Thanks.